# Maps v3 Autocomplete Fires event place_changed without clicking

Tags: events, autocomplete, maps, onblur

i have an issue trying to disable the event place_changed from an autocomplete on blur, as soon as i type, the list pop-ups and you can navigate with the arrows through the list, if i click an option, it fires place_changed, that works fine, but if i navigate through the options with the arrow keys, and left one option with focus, if i simple click outside without selecting, it does fire place_changed too...

That behavior isn't what i want, cause i feel anyone will find clicking outside as,ignoring whatever you were doing, like... "Hey, i didnt select the options, i just navigated through them"

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: its only javascript api